# console based chat application in c

Tags: c, unix

i created this application in which two processes communicate. everything is well 
but **i want that when the user press esc the process ends automatically**.
s**econdly it is getting only one line from user. at a time in one process**. and before entering second line we have to add a line to the other process also.
here is the code for **process 1(i called server)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
extern int      errno;
#define FIFO1   "/tmp/fifo.1"
#define FIFO3   "/tmp/fifo.3"
#define PERMS   0666
#define MESSAGE1        "client Says:"

main()
{
    char buff[BUFSIZ];
    int readfd, writefd;
int n, size;
    if ((mknod (FIFO1, S_IFIFO | PERMS, 0) < 0) && (errno != EEXIST)) {
        perror ("mknod FIFO1");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (mkfifo(FIFO3, PERMS) < 0 && (errno != EEXIST)) {
        unlink (FIFO1);
        perror("mknod FIFO3");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((readfd = open(FIFO1, 0)) < 0) {
        perror ("open FIFO1");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((writefd = open(FIFO3, 1)) < 0) {
        perror ("open FIFO3");
        exit(1);
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
loop:
 while(1)
{



    if ((n = read(readfd, buff, 100)) < 0) {
        perror ("server read"); exit (1);
    }

write(1,MESSAGE1,strlen(MESSAGE1));
if (write(1, buff, n) != n) {
            perror ("client write2"); exit(1);
        }


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


while(1)
{

printf("server says:");
//strcpy(buff,"I say:");
fgets(buff,100,stdin);
n=strlen(buff) + 1;
    if (write(writefd, buff,n) < n) {
        perror("server write1"); exit (1);
    }
goto loop; 
}

}//end of first for 
    close (readfd); close (writefd);
}
```

the second process (i called client)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
extern int      errno;
#define FIFO1   "/tmp/fifo.1"
#define FIFO3   "/tmp/fifo.3"
#define PERMS   0666
#define MESSAGE1        "server Says:"


main()
{
    char buff[BUFSIZ];
char buf[]="logout";
    int readfd, writefd, n, size;
    if ((writefd = open(FIFO1, 1)) < 0) {
        perror ("client open FIFO1"); exit(1);
    }
    if ((readfd = open(FIFO3, 0)) < 0) {
        perror ("client open FIFO3"); exit(1);
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
loop:
while(1)
{

printf("client says:");
fgets(buff,100,stdin);
n=strlen(buff) + 1;
    if (write(writefd, buff,n) < n) 
    {
        perror("server write1"); exit (1);
        }

////////////////////////////////////////////
while(1)
{


    if ((n = read(readfd, buff, 100)) < 0) 
    {
        perror ("client read"); exit(1);
        }


    write(1,MESSAGE1,strlen(MESSAGE1));
        if (write(1, buff, n) != n) 
        {
            perror ("client write2"); exit(1);
        }


goto loop;
}
}//end of first for
    close(readfd); close(writefd);
     /* Remove FIFOs now that we are done using them */
    if (unlink (FIFO1) < 0) {
        perror("client unlink FIFO1");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (unlink (FIFO3) < 0) {
        perror("client unlink FIFO3");
        exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why the `goto loop`? If you want to exit a loop you should use `break`.

Comment: Also, why use `mknod` for the first FIFO?

Comment: i dnt want to exit the loop i want that it allows the process to input lines as much as he wants

Comment: @joachim i just used that for learning purpose.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When you use `goto loop` in the inner loop, it exits the inner loop and starts over with the outer loop. If you put a `break` instead it would exit the inner loop, and since there are no more statements in the outer loop it would start over with the outer loop. So it's the same, but you do it in a way that is generally frowned upon.

Comment: @greydet the question is how can i display each line entered by the user on the other process. currently it displays only one line before i type on the other process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the two programs to be *non blocking*, i.e. they should be able to read from *either* the user *or* from the pipe.

If that is the case then I suggest you look into the [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/select.html) system call. It can be used to poll for input from arbitrary file descriptors.

You could do something like the following pseudo-code:

```
while (1)
{
    /* Poll for input */
    select(...);

    if (is_pipe_readable())
        read_from_pipe_and_print_to_stdout();
    else if (is_stdin_readable())
        read_from_stdin_and_write_to_pipe();
}
```

Note that a file descriptor becomes readable when it's been closed. So if the write-end of a pipe is closed, the read-end becomes readable, with `read` returning zero.

Comment: Also investigate terminal modes (cooked and raw). Typically terminals hand out one line at a time (and you are using fgets anyway). It sounds like you want to have 1 char at a time which will mean selecting raw mode and using read to get whatever is available when select indicates a file descriptor is ready for reading.

Comment: the thing i want to do is that as i write in process 1 . it is displays on both the process 1 and process 2. and vice versa.

Comment: @AmberAslam You want to send a character at a time? This polling method can still be used, just read/write a character at a time.

Comment: it might do but i'm newbie and i dont about such advance code yet. my code is working f9. the only help i neeed is that how can i display multiple lines??

Comment: @AmberAslam As far as I can see, your programs already does that. The problem you have is that they gets stuck in the `fgets` call, and wont read anything from the pipe unless you enter some input. If you want to write multiple lines in one of the programs, and the other program should be able to read that from the pipe _as well_ as checking for input from its own user, then you need to do some kind of polling as outlined in my answer.